# You have an error in your SQL syntax while building query with raw select in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to run this query

```
        $revs = DB::table('reviews')->where('website_id', $website_id)
                    ->selectRaw('
                    COUNT(id) AS total_count,
                    COUNT(id) AS third_party_reviews_count WHERE review_source_id!=1,
                    COUNT(id) AS normal_reviews_count WHERE review_source_id=1,
                    COUNT(id) AS total_1_star WHERE stars = 1,
                    COUNT(id) AS total_2_star WHERE stars = 2,
                    COUNT(id) AS total_3_star WHERE stars = 3,
                    COUNT(id) AS total_4_star WHERE stars = 4,
                    COUNT(id) AS total_5_star WHERE stars = 5')->get();
```

but it says

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(id) AS normal_reviews_count WHERE `review_source_id`=1,COUNT(id) AS
```

I tried using online SQL syntax checkers but none gave me a solution to the problem.

Comment: You cannot use `WHERE` like that.

Comment: And how can I use it in my case then?

Comment: I think you should start by setting out what the query needs to do, formulate it according to the MySQL syntax rules, test it to make sure it works, and only then try to use the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the whole sql query and then run it like that:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS total_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN review_source_id != 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS third_party_reviews_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN review_source_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS normal_reviews_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stars = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_1_star,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stars = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_2_star,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stars = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_3_star,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stars = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_4_star,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stars = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_5_star
FROM
    reviews 
WHERE
    website_id = $website_id
SQL;

$revs = DB::select($sql);
```